# how do I disable my screen lock pin on my galaxy tab 3?

Tags: lock-screens

I added a screen lock pin number on my galaxy tab 3 but my children play the games and I am not always around to enter it.  How do I disable it?

Answer (score 5):

If it's running standard firmware, you should go to `Menu > Settings > Security > Lock Screen > Screen Lock > None`. For the Galaxy Tab, I'd presume it'd be something similar to that.

Comment: I tried that before, but on the Galaxy tab 3 "Security" and "Lock Screen" are separate and in the same column. When I tap "Security", there is no option called "Screen Lock".  When I tap "Lock Screen", there is an option called "Screen Lock", but in smaller letters under this option it says "Secured with PIN". When I tap "Screen Lock" I only get the option "Confirm PIN".

Comment: The system needs your current password in order to allow you to change the security settings.  Otherwise it wouldn't be very secure :)  After confirming your PIN, the other options should appear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and just figured it out.  Go to `Settings -> Lock Screen,` then un-check the box next to `Lock instantly with Power key` (5th from the top).

Disregard the other suggestions offered.  This is all you have to do to turn it off.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's exciting to have new members around to ask questions, but let's not tell people to "disregard . . . other suggestions".